# paypal IPN subscr_payment for pending payments

Tags: paypal

When having a pending subscription payment (such as an e-check) is subscr_payment still called? I couldn't seem to find any document about it.

Answer (score 2):

subscr_payment is still called with a status of "Pending" it is then called again when the payment clears with a status of "Completed"